# How to use android Volley along with realm to perform network related task in the android app

Tags: android, android-volley, realm

I want to use Android Volley for transmitting network data and I am using Realm database. I don't know whether it is possible to use both volley and realm? If yes then how? If not then why?

Comment: Your question is way too vague.  I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, you can use both Volley and Realm in the same app.  But what do you mean, "how"?  What sort of answer are you expecting?  Those two libraries are for totally unrelated functions, so just use them both.

Answer (score -1):

To implement realm go through this site [Realm Implementation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)
To implement Volley go through this site [Volley Implementation](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

You can use both in your app